# How can I get a list of users who have the same phone number in Zendesk?

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api, zendesk-app

I have a setup for Zendesk where tickets are created using multiple methods. One of these methods is via MyFusion Notes, and with this method, a new ticket and a new user is created in the database, with nothing more than the phone number, in this format: +1 (555) 555-5555.

Now, when the same customer calls, the same happens, but the phone number comes up like this: +15555555555

The problem is that when the customer called again, that new phone number format is not recognized as already in the system, and a new user is created.

What I want to do, is to first get a list of users where this happened. In database querying terms, I want something similar to `SELECT * FROM users GROUP BY phone having count(*) >= 2`. Then I can figure out how to merge these users or just delete the empty ones.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Search API in Zendesk? 
https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/search

Comment: I don't know how to use the Search API to find duplicated records. All I found out how to do is to do specific queries, but nothing to find more complicated queries like duplicated records..

Comment: @andrux, if I'm not mistaken, you'd just enter your search query, and if there are multiple records that match the query, then they'd be returned and depending on the specificity of the query, there may be a high chance they are duplicates.  If using phone number for a user record, you can specify to return only user records `type:user` if I'm not mistaken, and then `phone:1203802382`.  Zendesk won't specifically tell you they are duplicates, so you'd still have to determine that on your own.